# Android: Horizontal RecyclerView Layout with Cards is cutting off the bottom of larger layouts

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-cardview, horizontal-scrolling

It seems that the later cards (1st photo) are being cropped to the size of the biggest card that’s in the initial view (see card marked with red in 2nd photo). All the cards that would be bigger than that have the bottom of the view cut off/wrapped. I’m using a MaterialCardView with a ConstraintLayout inside that holds all the views you see in the card. The CardView, ConstraintLayout, and RecyclerView all have `layout_height=wrap_content`. I've tried changing `setHasFixedSize()` and a number of other random things around layout_height/width.

Any ideas to why that would be happening?

[image: cards with cut bottom view cut]

[image: initial_view]

Answer (score 0):

probably you put a `android:layout_marginBottom` on red marked card and using that for all of your cards . that will prevent the cards to show they're full content .
you can make you font or images smaller or change that `android:layout_marginBottom`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That didn't seem to work. Since I'm getting the data from a service, I'm not sure what will be in it so each cards size will be different. After doing some more research, I finally found some others that asked a similar question, and it doesn't seem like there's a great solution